# Oxygen for manned missions

Tags: future-missions, oxygen, mission-control

What are some techniques/ways to provide enough oxygen for some manned mission that would last, say, years?

**edited**

I mean some arbitrary mission departing from earth  to infinity and beyond... No particular destination, just in the opposite direction from the sun, and for a very, very long time. The passengers would remain inside the space ship, which would continue to wonder away from the earth indefinitely...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Providing sufficient oxygen for a long journey is not the challenge.  If you have enough to meet the demands for a week, you have enough to meet the demands forever. Oxygen is not destroyed or created in [respiration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecosystem_respiration) Animals (people) take in [oxygen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen) where there are two atoms joined together and exhale [Carbon Dioxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide) where there are is a carbon between the two oxygen atoms.  On earth plants take in Carbon Dioxide keep the carbon, and release oxygen.

The challenge is two fold.

1. Having enough oxygen to replace any that escapes from your vehicle
2. Having enough energy to power the recyling system, which can be mechanical or biological.

See related questions

- [Oxygen self-supply by plants](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2218/oxygen-self-supply-by-plants)
- [What would have happened if the skin of an Apollo lunar module was ruptured?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/924/what-would-have-happened-if-the-skin-of-an-apollo-lunar-module-was-ruptured)
- [Would a biological resource-system be feasible for long-term manned flights?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/449/would-a-biological-resource-system-be-feasible-for-long-term-manned-flights)
- [Is converting moon dust into oxygen a viable option for sustainability?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14/is-converting-moon-dust-into-oxygen-a-viable-option-for-sustainability)

Comment: You are giving the impression that all of the oxygen breathed in ends up in CO2. It does not.  It also ends up in water and many waste products.  To recycle all of the oxygen would take a much more involved approach than just splitting CO2.  Your statement on plants is not complete: plants take in carbon dioxide and water and sunlight, and release oxygen and store sugars.  Even that statement is oversimplified.  Recovering all of the oxygen breathed is a _huge_ challenge.  It's not just about preventing escape and providing energy.  Those in fact are the two easiest to solve.

Comment: @MarkAdler completely agree. some of that is addressed in links in the answer.  But the totality of the complexities is beyond the scope of a single answer and beyond what (*I believed*) the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Sure.  Just replicate the ecosystems of the Earth and the power source of the Sun sufficiently to provide a closed cycle.  The Earth and Sun are such a spaceship.

You can buy such closed systems (Sun not included) with plants, animals and bacteria.

[image: ecosphere]

They are called "ecospheres".  They work thusly:

[image: eco cycle]

If you really want something "indefinite", biological systems are self-replicating, self-repairing, and will even evolve over time to better meet your needs if you cull the populations that don't meet your needs.

As for replicating the Sun if you're far from any star, that would require nuclear power in any practical system of long duration.  You could use existing fission systems, or, we can hope, future fusion systems.  And bring enough fuel.  You could in theory collect interstellar hydrogen, but that is not likely to be practical.  Truly "indefinite" is not possible, and is limited by the fuel you can bring or find.  The same is true of our Sun.

Comment: Cool. So about how much space would something like that take up so that it's big enough to generate enough oxygen for one human per "cycle" (day/hour/etc)?

Comment: Not known.  A [human-occupied ecosphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biosphere_2) was attempted twice, but failed.

Comment: You might want to add that to your answer, as this is a massively complex way to generate oxygen and a currently unsolved problem for anything larger than a toy.

Comment: For continuing "to wander away from the Earth indefinitely", it is currently the _only_ solution that would recycle all waste products (not just CO2) and allow for a truly closed system that could work indefinitely.  I would go so far as to claim the the eventual solution for generation ships will be the product of bioengineering (including genetic engineering), not chemical engineering.  Bioengineered solutions reproduce themselves, providing their own maintenance.  Chemical engineering plants are generally not self-reproducing or self-repairing.

Comment: There's a flaw in the reasoning here, however - biospheres rely on energy from the Sun to sustain themselves, and as one wanders further in- or out-system, the amount of available energy from the sun changes. A Sun-reliant biosphere would not be very useful out beyond the asteroid belt.

Comment: @Amber: you seem to have missed the part in the answer about a nuclear power source.

Comment: @MarkAdler I did miss that part, but if you're going that route, that's not "recycling all waste products" as your comment states - you'd still have nuclear waste and eventually run out of nuclear fuel. If you're bringing nuclear fuel, then the biome part is pointless.

Comment: Yes, truly "indefinitely" is not possible since you will eventually run out of fuel.  But so will our Sun.  I meant a closed system on human waste products.  I will edit the answer to clarify that.

Comment: @Amber: by the way, your comment implies that the Earth biome is pointless, since the Sun will eventually run out of nuclear fuel.  I would not contest that conclusion.  :-)